# A problem with processing data from html form with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm just about to learn php and that is my first try to process data from an html form. I was writing this php code using some articles from the Internet and it seems to be correct but after entering all the data and than pressing "submit" nothing is happening. I mean just a white browser screen.

Here is my code:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="post" action="form__2.php">
    <label for="surname">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Johnson" required> <br>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Carl" required> <br>



    <label>Gender:</label>
    <label for="male">M</label>
    <input type="radio" name="male" checked>
    <label for="female">F</label>
    <input type="radio" name="female"> <br>

    <label for="education">Education:</label>
    <select id="education" name="education" required>
      <option value="less-basic">Less than basic</option>
      <option value="basic">Basic</option>
      <option value="mid-school">Middle-school</option>
      <option value="high-school">High-school</option>
      <option value="bachelor">Bachelor's or equivalent</option>
      <option value="master">Master's or equivalent</option>
      <option value="doctor">Doctorate or equivalent</option>
    </select> <br>

    <label for="courses">Enroll in courses</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" required> <br>

    <label>Was you dealing with our company later?:</label>
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="company" value="yes" checked>
    <label>No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="company" value="no"> <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?
        if ( count($_GET) > 0 ) // checking if the form sends any data
        {
            $name = htmlspecialchars($_GET['name']); // getting name from GET-values
            $surname = htmlspecialchars($_GET['surname']); // getting surname from GET-values
        if ( strlen($_GET['name']) >= 1 && strlen($_GET['surname']) >= 1) // if the name/surname has more than 1 letter, then..
         {
            echo "Dear " . $surname . " " . $name . ". We are great to have you signed for our courses. We are hoping for "; // msg
            if ( $_POST['company_yes']=='yes' ) // if radiobutton is checked
            { 
                echo "continuing our partnership."; // msg
            } else
            {
                echo "our future partnership."; // msg
            }
         } else
         {
            echo "Your name is too short";
         }
         }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the PHP code visible in the page source in your browser's debugging tools?

Comment: The name and surname are in `$_POST`, not `$_GET`.

Comment: Your form's action is POST, but the first thing the action script does is check for GET values.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't check if a Post happened, and why call to GET request if you send a post request?

1. A GET request is data that passes through the URL -> https://www.something.net?data=hi
   $_GET['data'] will give "hi" value.
2. POST is data that is passed mostly through forms with `method="POST"`

To get the data of the form change the form__2.php to the following:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']){ //the name of the submit button
  echo $_POST['education'];
  echo $_POST['female'];
}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
   
</body>
</html>
```